# Wallaby.js hangs during initalization

Tags: visual-studio-2013, wallaby.js

I'm trying to get Wallaby.js running on my solution in VS2013 and I'm getting some weird behaviour.

If it is running and I change the config file I have to stop it. It errors with the following message

> wallaby.js started core v1.0.159 Failed to start stop operation,
>   Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, unlink
>   'C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\1.wallaby\projects\FG57vVlzA+WewEWCpi1WInb+g1k=\cache\instrumented\somepath\somefile.ts.compiled.js'
>   at Error (native)   at Object.fs.unlinkSync
>   (evalmachine.:931:18)   at EventEmitter.u.unlinkFileSync
>   [as _unlinkFileSync] (C:\Users\XXXX.wallaby\core\server.js:18:11095) 
>   at C:\Users\XXXX.wallaby\core\server.js:16:6022   at baseFor
>   (C:\Users\XXXX.wallaby\core\node_modules\lodash\index.js:1971:13)
>   at baseForOwn
>   (C:\Users\XXXX.wallaby\core\node_modules\lodash\index.js:2025:14)
>   at baseEach
>   (C:\Users\XXXX.wallaby\core\node_modules\lodash\index.js:1814:16)
>   at Function.forEach
>   (C:\Users\XXXX.wallaby\core\node_modules\lodash\index.js:5701:11)
>   at EventEmitter._.extend.stop
>   (C:\Users\XXXX.wallaby\core\server.js:16:5651)   at Object.i.receive
>   (C:\Users\XXXX.wallaby\core\server.js:14:1177)   at
>   WebSocket. (C:\Users\XXXX.wallaby\core\server.js:18:12016)
>   at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)   at WebSocket.emit (events.js:169:7)
>   at Receiver.self._receiver.ontext
>   (C:\Users\XXXX.wallaby\core\node_modules\ws\lib\WebSocket.js:682:10) 
>   at Receiver.opcodes.1.finish
>   (C:\Users\XXXX.wallaby\core\node_modules\ws\lib\Receiver.js:391:14)
>   at Receiver.expectHandler
>   (C:\Users\XXXX.wallaby\core\node_modules\ws\lib\Receiver.js:372:33)
>   at Receiver.add
>   (C:\Users\XXXX.wallaby\core\node_modules\ws\lib\Receiver.js:87:24)
>   at Socket.firstHandler
>   (C:\Users\XXXX.wallaby\core\node_modules\ws\lib\WebSocket.js:663:22) 
>   at emitOne (events.js:77:13)   at Socket.emit (events.js:166:7)   at
>   readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:146:16)   at
>   Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:109:10)   at TCP.onread
>   (net.js:517:20)
>
> wallaby.js stopped

Then I start Wallaby.js and it hangs on the initialization stage, as indicated in the bottom left corner of VS2013

> Wallaby.js: Initializing runner

and the console output never moves past

> wallaby.js started
>   core v1.0.159

I then stop Wallaby.js and nothing happens.

I then stop Wallaby.js and the console reports Wallaby.js has stopped (The context menu for my config file show stop, restart, and start cmd's)

> wallaby.js started
>   core v1.0.159
>   wallaby.js stopped

Then I start Wallaby.js again, and it works...

I followed the steps outline for installing Wallaby.js and have been fumbling my way through the configuration doco. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, please create a small repo on GitHub demonstrating the issue and share the repo link in our public repo issues at https://github.com/wallabyjs/public/issues, happy to have a look.

Comment: @ArtemGovorov I'll see what I can do, I don't have much time at the moment. My feeling is that this is more of an environmemtal issue rather than the project/solution structure. It looks like Wallaby can't read/write where it wants too.

Comment: @ArtemGovorov and thanks!

Comment: Cool, thanks! It does seem like that, Anyway, as I understand the issue is not blocking, is it? In a sense that everything starts eventually.

Comment: Correct, it isn't blocking us trialing Wallaby. We have bigger issues with ordering references

Comment: Re: ordering, from the stack tarce I have noticed you're sing TypeScript, so perhaps this could help: http://wallabyjs.com/docs/integration/typescript.html#ordering-source-files-with-reference-comments

Comment: BTW, as I have answered in another question, remove leading `./` from all of your wallaby config paths, it may be the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is most certainly the result of leading `./` in your files/tests paths/patterns in your wallaby config. Please remove t and try again.